# swing Jform creating

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jcomponent

**Here is my code the problem is that i can't find why one extra form is create**

```
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
           submitBtn.setForeground(Color.red);               
           //getting value form the textFields
           String name = nameTxt.getText();
           String userName = userNameTxt.getText();
           char[] pass = password.getPassword();
           Object monthValue = month.getSelectedItem();
           String yearValue = yearTxt.getText();
           String dateValue = dateTxt.getText();
           Object genderValue = gender.getSelectedItem();
           String mobileValue = mobileTxt.getText();
           Object locationValue = country.getSelectedItem();

           showDetails page = new showDetails();
           page.setVisible(true);
           JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
           contentPane.setLayout(null);
           contentPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("user Details"));
           JLabel nameVL = new JLabel("Name             :            " + name );
           nameVL.setBounds(80, 30, 200, 200);
           contentPane.add(nameVL); 
           page.getContentPane().add(contentPane);               
        }
```

**above code is in signuppage.java class**

**and i create a form to display result of the label into showDetails class**

```
public class showDetails extends JFrame {

    Dimension screen = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

    public showDetails() {
        JFrame showFrame = new JFrame("user details");
        showFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        showFrame.setSize(300, 400);
        showFrame.setVisible(true);
        showFrame.setLocation((screen.width - 500)/2,((screen.height-350)/2));
    }
}
```

but my problem is that the result is not show in the showFram insteed of this one form is created don't know how....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ShowDeatils` extends from `JFrame`, while in its constructor, you are creating another `JFrame`, therefore, you're creating two frames every time you create a new instance of `showDetails`

**Updated**

Basically, or you need to do is...

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
        submitBtn.setForeground(Color.red);               
        //getting value form the textFields
        String name = nameTxt.getText();
        String userName = userNameTxt.getText();
        char[] pass = password.getPassword();
        Object monthValue = month.getSelectedItem();
        String yearValue = yearTxt.getText();
        String dateValue = dateTxt.getText();
        Object genderValue = gender.getSelectedItem();
        String mobileValue = mobileTxt.getText();
        Object locationValue = country.getSelectedItem();

        JFrame showFrame = new JFrame("user details");
        showFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        showFrame.setSize(300, 400);
        showFrame.setLocation((screen.width - 500)/2,((screen.height-350)/2));  

        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setLayout(null);
        contentPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("user Details"));
        JLabel nameVL = new JLabel("Name             :            " + name );
        nameVL.setBounds(80, 30, 200, 200);
        contentPane.add(nameVL); 

        showFrame.getContentPane().add(contentPane);               
        showFrame.setVisible(true);
        showFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
```

Comment: if i don't use extends JFrame result is not displed into frame that was created in showdetails class why so...

Comment: good catch, [btw I think that 1st or last could be best for you](http://www.australia.com/best-jobs.aspx)

Comment: @user1857 Then don't create the frame with in the constructor.

Comment: if i remove extends JFrame and creating frame within constructor then frame is created bt no result is desplayed in it..... @MadProgrammer

Comment: @user1857 That's because your adding your content from the action performed...and I would avoid null layouts

Comment: @MadProgrammer then i should use it outside the action performed actully i am new in java swing don't have idea u help me alot.

Comment: @MadProgrammer then it is also wrong in my code to create object in action performed.. if yes then where will be it.. and please tell me by removing extends JFrame it is showing error in page.getContentPane().add(contentPane);

Comment: @user1857 I've added an example

Comment: @MadProgrammer thank you for your help.. can you suggest me any tutorial for learing swing

Comment: I'd recommend starting with [Creating a GUI with Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)